# Extract first word after specific word

Tags: regex, perl

I'm having difficulty writing a Perl program to extract the word following a certain word.

For example:

```
Today i'm not  going anywhere except to office.
```

I want the word after `anywhere`, so the output should be `except`.

I have tried this

```
my $words = "Today i'm not  going anywhere except to office.";
my $w_after = ( $words =~ /anywhere (\S+)/ );
```

but it seems this is wrong.

Comment: You can accept answers from the below updates.

Comment: @ssr1012: One may also wait a day or two to see if a better answer appears

Comment: @Borodin: OP said/confirms `it helps` for `Jim Garrison` answers. Hence I requested here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very close:

```
my ($w_after) = ($words =~ /anywhere\s+(\S+)/);
   ^        ^                       ^^^
   +--------+                        |
     Note 1                        Note 2
```

Note 1: `=~` returns a *list* of captured items, so the assignment target needs to be a list.

Note 2: allow one or more blanks after `anywhere`

Comment: @JimGarrison Can you explain the use of `()`.?  `my ($w_after) = $words =~ /anywhere\s+(\S+)/;` it is also give the same result then why.?

Comment: @mkHun that is used for operator precedence. In this case `=~` has higher prcedence than `=` that's why giving same result.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl v5.22 and later, you can use `\b{wb}` to get better results for natural language.  The pattern could be

```
/anywhere\b{wb}.+?\b{wb}(.+?\b{wb})/
```

"wb" stands for word break, and it will account for words that have apostrophes in them, like "I'll", that plain `\b` doesn't.

```
.+?\b{wb}
```

matches the shortest non-empty sequence of characters that don't have a word break in them.  The first one matches the span of spaces in your sentence; and the second one matches "except".  It is enclosed in parentheses, so upon completion `$1` contains "except".

`\b{wb}` is documented most fully in [perlrebackslash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to write parentheses around left side expression of `=` operator to force array context for regexp evaluation. See [`m//` and `//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#m%2f_PATTERN_%2fmsixpodualngc) in [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) documentation.[1] You can write 
parentheses also around [`=~`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators) binding operator to improve readability but it is not necessary because `=~` has pretty high [priority](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity).

Use [POSIX Character Classes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#POSIX-Character-Classes) `word`

```
my ($w_after) = ($words =~ / \b anywhere \W+ (\w+) \b /x);
```

Note I'm using `x` so whitespaces in regexp are ignored. Also use `\b` word boundary to anchor regexp correctly.

[1]: I write `my ($w_after)` just for convenience because you can write `my ($a, $b, $c, @rest)` as equivalent of `(my $a, my $b, my $c, my @rest)` but you can also control scope of your variables like `(my $a, our $UGLY_GLOBAL, local $_, @_)`.

Comment: Whilst your answer is correct, the thing the OP needs is the `my ( $w_after ) ` so it does the assignment in a list context. I think it would be useful to spell that out.

Answer (score -1):

This Regex to be matched:

```
my ($expect) = ($words=~m/anywhere\s+([^\s]+)\s+/);
```

`^\s+` the word between two spaces

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to also take into consideration the punctuation marks, like in:

```
my $words = "Today i'm not going anywhere; except to office.";
```

Then try this:

```
my ($w_after) = ($words =~ /anywhere[[:punct:]|\s]+(\S+)/);
```